# multi-monitor organize desktop by name bug

Tags: unity, multiple-monitors, resolution, icons

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04LTS with Unity, and using two monitors: my notebook build-in display, 1366x768 and an external monitor at 1920x1080 resolution.

my primary monitor is the built-in, and so, when I right-click the desktop and "organize desktop by name", the icons go to it, and get aligned.

the problem happens when I have many icons to align, and Unity sends some icons to below my visible screen, probably considering the bigger monitor resolution.

I tested selecting all aligned icons (ctrl+a) and dragging to the bigger monitor, but it seems that the icons that got hidden also got overlapped above each-others.

anyway, it seems to be a bug, right?

I haven't checked 14.10 yet to see if this is fixed.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes I am having the same problem.. I click "organize desktop by name" then the icons go off screen and I have to ctrl-A to bring them back into view.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a script to update the position of icons. The script makes the icons fit in the screen, whatever your screen resolution is.

It is slow and takes a little bit more than 1 second on my machine for 100 files. But at least it works. There may be better way to achieve this though...

Copy and paste the code below in a file name "arrange_icons.sh". In a terminal, run `chmod 755 /path/to/arrange_icons.sh`. Run the script with `/path/to/arrange_icons.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

######################################################
## Script to automatically arrange desktop icons
## taking into account screen resolution of multiple
## monitors
######################################################

# Sort icons by...
sortby=name
# sortby=none
# sortby=time
# sortby=size
# sortby=extension
# sortby=version

# Maximum size of the grid (distance between two icons)
grid_size=85

# top, right, bottom and left margin of the screen
grid_margintop=25
grid_marginright=50
grid_marginbottom=50
grid_marginleft=50

# Filling order
# Default: fill from top to bottom, then change column from left to right
# A regular english book is written using leftright-topbottom
grid_fill=topbottom-leftright
# grid_fill=topbottom-rightleft
# grid_fill=bottomtop-leftright
# grid_fill=bottomtop-rightleft
# grid_fill=leftright-topbottom
# grid_fill=leftright-bottomtop
# grid_fill=rightleft-topbottom
# grid_fill=rightleft-bottomtop

# Find the Desktop path as it may vary from language to language
# Path to home sub-directories are located in ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs
source ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs
DESKTOP="${XDG_DESKTOP_DIR}"

# Count desktop file
icon_number=$(ls "${DESKTOP}" | wc -l)

# Find monitors, dimensions and positions, and store all icon position to temp file
tmp=/tmp/arrange_icons.position-$RANDOM$RANDOM$RANDOM
while :
do
  # Empty the file storing icon positions
  printf '' > "${tmp}"

  xrandr | grep -oE '[0-9]+x[0-9]+\+[0-9]+\+[0-9]+' | while read screen
  do
    width=$(echo ${screen} | cut -d 'x' -f 1)
    height=$(echo ${screen} | cut -d 'x' -f 2 | cut -d '+' -f 1)
    cx=$(echo ${screen} | cut -d 'x' -f 2 | cut -d '+' -f 2)
    cy=$(echo ${screen} | cut -d 'x' -f 2 | cut -d '+' -f 3)

    for px in $(seq $((cx + grid_marginleft)) ${grid_size} $((cx + grid_marginleft + width - grid_size - grid_marginright)))
    do
      for py in $(seq $((cy + grid_margintop)) ${grid_size} $((cy + grid_margintop + height - grid_size - grid_marginbottom)))
      do
        echo "${px},${py}" >> "${tmp}"
      done
    done
  done

  # Count the number of positions available with this grid
  grid_number=$(cat "${tmp}" | wc -l)

  # If it is not possible to fit every icons, try to decrease the size of the grid
  # until it fits or until the grid size reaches the minimum value (1)
  if [ ${grid_number} -lt ${icon_number} ]
  then
    grid_size=$((grid_size - 5))
    if [ ${grid_size} -lt 1 ]
    then
      grid_size=1
      break
    fi
  else
    break;
  fi
done

# Sort position according to settings
case "${grid_fill}" in
  topbottom-leftright) sort -o "${tmp}" -t, -k 1,1n -k 2,2n "${tmp}"
                       ;;
  topbottom-rightleft) sort -o "${tmp}" -t, -k 1,1rn -k 2,2n "${tmp}"
                       ;;
  bottomtop-leftright) sort -o "${tmp}" -t, -k 1,1n -k 2,2rn "${tmp}"
                       ;;
  bottomtop-rightleft) sort -o "${tmp}" -t, -k 1,1rn -k 2,2rn "${tmp}"
                       ;;
  leftright-topbottom) sort -o "${tmp}" -t, -k 2,2n -k 1,1n "${tmp}"
                       ;;
  leftright-bottomtop) sort -o "${tmp}" -t, -k 2,2rn -k 1,1n "${tmp}"
                       ;;
  rightleft-topbottom) sort -o "${tmp}" -t, -k 2,2n -k 1,1n "${tmp}"
                       ;;
  rightleft-bottomtop) sort -o "${tmp}" -t, -k 2,2rn -k 1,1n "${tmp}"
                       ;;
                    *) sort -o "${tmp}" -t, -k 1,1n -k 2,2n "${tmp}"
                       ;;
esac

# List all files on the desktop and move them to the correct location
line_number=1

# Temporary path for icon
# Moving them to /tmp folder and then moving them back to the Desktop
# is sufficient to update their position :)
tmpicon=/tmp/arrange_icons.fake-$RANDOM$RANDOM$RANDOM
([ "${sortby}" != "name" ] && ls --sort=${sortby} "${DESKTOP}" || ls "${DESKTOP}") | while read icon
do
  iconpath="${DESKTOP}/${icon}"
  coord="$(tail -n+${line_number} "${tmp}" | head -n1)"

  gvfs-set-attribute -t string "${iconpath}" 'metadata::nautilus-icon-position' "${coord}"
  mv "${iconpath}" "${tmpicon}"
  mv "${tmpicon}" "${iconpath}"

  line_number=$((line_number + 1))
done

# Cleaning
rm "${tmp}"
```

On my machine, I set a crontab that checks every second the Desktop folder. If something has changed, the script above is run.